# How to cast a generic Type to fit another generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method in Class A

```
public IList<T> MyMethod<T>() where T:AObject
```

I want to invoke this method in another generic class B. This T is without any constraints.

```
public mehtodInClassB(){
    if (typeof(AObject)==typeof(T))
    {
      //Compile error here, how can I cast the T to a AObject Type
      //Get the MyMethod data
        A a = new A();
        a.MyMethod<T>();
    }
}
```

Class C is inherited from Class AObject.

```
B<C> b = new B<C>();
b.mehtodInClassB()
```

any thoughts?

**After urs reminding...Update:**

Yes. What I actually want to do is

```
typeof(AObject).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

not

```
typeof(AObject)==typeof(T))
```

Comment: If we could see more of what the other class does, we might be able to provide more relevant advice.

Comment: what is the type of `d`? if it is the right type can you not just call MyMethod on it without bothering to pass the type parameter (eg `d.MyMethod()`)?

Comment: @Chris The method is generic and takes no arguments. You can't omit the generic type parameter in this case because there is no way to infer it from usage.

Comment: @ChrisHannon: Ah yes, my bad. :) Forgot that it coudln't use return type to determine anything. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know that `T` is an `AObject`, why not just provide `AObject` as the type parameter to `MyMethod`:

```
if (typeof(AObject).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
  //Compile error here, how can I cast the T to a AObject Type
  //Get the MyMethod data
    d.MyMethod<AObject>();
}
```

If providing `AObject` as a type parameter is not an option, you'll have to put the same constraint on `T` in the calling method:

```
void Caller<T>() where T: AObject
{
    // ...

    d.MyMethod<T>();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Because AObject is baseclass here

Comment: You know what though, `typeof(T)` will only equal `typeof(AObject)` if `T` is `AObject`. I think you meant `typeof(AObject).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, unless you put the same constraint on the containing method.  Generics are checked at compile time so you can't make runtime decisions like that.

Alternatively, you can use reflection to invoke the method, it just takes a little more code.

See this SO question for more info on how to do that: [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Comment: Surely you can make runtime decisions as long as you tell the compiler what the decisions are. If you cast to AObject explicitly then the compiler will know its an AObject and can work appropriately.

Comment: @Chris How do you do casting on a generic parameter?

Comment: @Chris The problem here is AObject is a base class. The T can be a AObject's derived class, no idea how to cast it.

Comment: @ValidfroM You can't cast a generic parameter, so if Dan's answer doesn't work for you, then you'll have to use reflection.